# I don't know how to use filesystem to look for .txt files c++

Tags: c++, c++17, txt, std-filesystem

I would like to use `std::filesystem` in my project, which will allow me to show `.txt` files in the current directory (I use Ubuntu, I don't need a Windows function because I have already seen one on StackOverflow).

Here is my GitHub repo:

https://github.com/jaroslawroszyk/-how-many-pages-per-day

I have a fix for this problem like this:

```cpp
void showFilesTxt()
{
    DIR *d;
    char *p1, *p2;
    int ret;
    struct dirent *dir;
    d = opendir(".");
    if (d)
    {
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
        {
            p1 = strtok(dir->d_name, ".");
            p2 = strtok(NULL, ".");
            if (p2 != NULL)
            {
                ret = strcmp(p2, "txt");
                if (ret == 0)
                {
                    std::cout << p1 << "\n";
                }
            }
        }
        closedir(d);
    }
}
```

But the code I enter here would like to use C++17, but I don't know how to find the `.txt` files, now I wrote:

```cpp
for (auto &fn : std::filesystem::directory_iterator("."))
    if (std::filesystem::is_regular_file(fn))
    {
        std::cout << fn.path() << '\n';
    }
```

Comment: I assume that the C++17 tag means that you can't use C++20 library additions?

Comment: yes you can use c++20

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look into the reference (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) you will find the `extension()` method on paths (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/extension) which returns you the file's extension. Now you simply need to use the `string()` function on the path's extension and compare the string.

Something like

```
for (auto& p : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(".")) {
    if (p.is_regular_file()) {
        if (p.path().extension().string() == ".txt") {
            std::cout << p << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that a `directory_iterator` dereferences to a `directory_entry`, not a `path`, so you would need to use `p.path().extension()` instead of `p.extension()`. Also, you can use `p.is_regular_file()` instead of `std::filesystem::is_regular_file(p.path())`. And, you can use `string() == ".txt"` instead of `string().compare(".txt") == 0`.

Answer (score 2):

In C++20, you can just check if the `path().string()` ends with `.txt` by using the [`std::string::ends_with`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/ends_with) member function:

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    for(auto& de : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(".")) {
        if(de.is_regular_file() && de.path().string().ends_with(".txt")) {
            std::cout << de << '\n';     // or `de.path().string()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how to remove "./" at the beginning and the extension so that it was not visible in the program operation

Comment: @JarosławRoszyk If the files are all in the same directory, you can do `std::cout << de.path().filename()` to only get the filename part of the path. If you later decide to do a recursive search, only printing the filename may be confusing though.

Comment: Thank you so much, you can use c++ 20 but I haven't studied it yet, I stopped at c ++ 11/14

Comment: @JarosławRoszyk You're welcome! Glad it helped! You have many helper functions if you look at [`std::filesystem::path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) that you can use to do fun stuff with. The `path` has iterators so you can loop over the individual components (directories) in the path too.

Comment: I know, but I have to understand how to read c reference because sometimes I go dumb

Comment: @JarosławRoszyk It took me a while to get used to cppreference too, but now it's my best friend :-)

Comment: I need to meet this friend haha